# UnsupportedClassVersionError Deploying webapp in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, tomcat7

I'm deploying a webapp in Tomcat7 which was built by Eclipse using Java Oracle 1.7.

I'm receiving this error which seems to indicate that different Java versions are being used.
However when I run java -version I get 'java version "1.7.0_51"' which is the same version as the compilation version.

It should be noted that this web app works fine in the eclipse tomcat server nenvironment, but doesn't seem to work when deploying in the main tomcat installation.

> 01-May-2014 00:37:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>   INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/prov.war
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   01-May-2014 00:37:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uk/co/alexjking/prov/ProvClustererWebApp/ClusterHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class uk.co.alexjking.prov.ProvClustererWebApp.ClusterHandler)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.processScannedResources(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:384)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.createDeployment(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:181)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.createDeployment(ListenerBootstrap.java:32)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:27)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
>       01-May-2014 00:37:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>       SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>       01-May-2014 00:37:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>       SEVERE: Context [/prov] startup failed due to previous errors
>       01-May-2014 00:37:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
>       SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextDestroyed(ResteasyBootstrap.java:37)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4819)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5466)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)

For completeness, this project has been built using Maven and uses Resteasy.

Comment: Tomcat is being run using a < 1.7 JRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tomcat configuration must be using a different java version. Check catalina.sh / catalina.bat, and check the java version mentioned in those files.
By default it uses JAVA_HOME so if you have set it correctly and have not played with tomcat sh/bat files then it should work.